# How can I get Binance historical data for different time intervals?

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to get OHLC data from Binance. The problem is I need to get data with different time intervals **(like 7 minutes, 28 minutes or so )** other than Binance API's standard time intervals( 1m, 3m, 5m, 15m, 30m, 1', 2h, 4h, 6h, 8h, 12h, 1d, 3d, 1w, 1M). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: My only idea is to collect data every minute and only use the data you need, although that is ideal.

Comment: Well I already thought about it but you can get at max 1000 different data with Binance API. If I do that this will decrease the data count. I still need the same amount of data.

Comment: I'm guessing that you probably need to look at the prices of crypto currency of something like this. My other idea would be to time your program to call the API at certain times and get the current information.